# Incorrect look and feel when using multicolumn

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn

So I'm trying to create 'subheadings' in my table, which before new rows start, a topic spanning all the columns is created to define what the next rows talk about. Here is an image so far:

[image]

As you can see the design of the table gets messed up, and the headings shouldn't be in the center. Using `\centering` or `\begin{center}\end{center}` every time seems a bit unnecessary right?

Here is the Latex code I'm using:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{8cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \textbf{Task} & \textbf{Start Date} & \textbf{Days to Complete}\\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{\textbf{Research}}\\
    \hline
    Compare and select target programming language & 08/01/2017 & 3\\
    Research and identify scanning and "infection" vectors & 08/01/2017 & 3\\
    Collect default root username/passwords & 08/01/2017 & 1\\
    Determine default IP ranges & 11/01/2017 & 1\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{\textbf{Design and Functionality}}\\
    \hline
    Mockup system design & 15/01/2017 & 2\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome :) Hmm, but it seems from my understanding of your code that you are explicitly centring the text in the subheadings with \multicolumn{3}{| c |} .... have you tried changing that to \multicolumn{3}{| l |}?

Comment: As @Tina stated, the `c` you specified means that the content of the cell will be centered. If you wanted it left aligned, then simply use `l`.

Comment: If you want it centered over the first two columns, use `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}`\\.